# How do I access cookie-session middleware in socket.io on NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, session, cookies, express, socket.io

I decided to use socket.io in my application and stumbled upon a problem. I use `cookie-session` for express authorization:

```
var session = require('cookie-session');
var app = express();
// ...
app.use(session({
  keys: ['secretkey1', 'secretkey2']
}))
// ...
app.get('/settings', function(req, res) {
    res.type("html");

    if (!req.session.sid)    {
        console.log("NO SID");
        req.session.sid = util.randomString();
    }
    else {
        console.log("sid:" + req.session.sid);
    }

    // doing stuff with req.session.sid

    var jadeView = { /*...*/ };
    res.status(200).send(mainJade(jadeView));
});
```

Now I use socket.io. I figured out how to access cookies:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    var cookie_string = socket.request.headers.cookie;
    console.log("cookies: " + cookie_string);
// ...
}
```

But how do I convert `cookie_string` to session object, like in `req.session`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### What changed

@rmflow's answer from 2014 does not seem to work in 2017 with [socket.io-client](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client) 2.0.2 and [cookie-session](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-session) 2.0.0

Apparently, the [cookies](https://github.com/pillarjs/cookies) package (the main dependency of cookie-session) expects somewhat different request and response objects. Namely, the request object should have a `connection` object with a boolean `encrypted` property; in addition, the response object is expected to have `getHeader` and `setHeader` methods.

### Updated solution

```
const session = require('cookie-session')({
    name: 'some-session-name',
    secret: 'some-session-secret', // or an array of keys as usual
    ... // Other relevant options
});

io.on('connection', socket => {
    let cookieString = socket.request.headers.cookie;

    let req = {connection: {encrypted: false}, headers: {cookie: cookieString}}
    let res = {getHeader: () =>{}, setHeader: () => {}};
    //
    session(req, res, () => {
        console.log(req.session); // Do something with req.session
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Figured out myself:

```
var req = { headers : {cookie : cookie_string} }
session({ keys: ['secretkey1', 'secretkey2'] })(req, {}, function(){})
console.log(req.session.sid);
```

Answer (score 0):

Update in 2024. Neither worked for me. I implemented a socket middleware et voila.

Imports and setup:

```js
import cookieSession from "cookie-session";
const session = cookieSession();

app.use(session);

const io = new Server(server)
```

Middleware:

```js
io.use((socket, next) => {
  let req = {
    headers: { cookie: socket.request.headers.cookie },
  };
  session(req, {}, () => {
    socket.session = req.session;
    next();
  });
});
```

Now sockets have a `session`:

```js
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("We have a session!", socket.session);
});
```

Note: this only works when headers are passed (only during first connection essentially), so when session is changed, these changes don't propagate to the socket object.